# Finding EMF from the given graphs

Tags: dc-motor, electromagnetism, faradays-law

[image]

Here are the graphs of flux vs angle and EMF vs angle.

From it, I have to derive the following relation (expected answer) between EMF -Ui and change in flux with respect to time.

[image]

My approach:

I find the function for every piecewise continuous graph which gives me the following result:

[image]

Φ=-B∙A,

Φ=((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙(φ-π/2),

Φ=B∙A, Φ=-((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙(φ-3π/2),

Φ=-B∙A

and lets me find the derivative of flux with respect to angle first which gives me:

dΦ/dϕ=(2B∙A)/(π-2θ),

dΦ/dϕ=-(2B∙A)/(π-2θ)

for two slopes and derivative of flux with respect to time comes out to be:

Ui= (dΦ/dϕ)∙(dϕ/dt)=((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙dϕ/dt,

Ui=(dΦ/dϕ)∙(dϕ/dt)=-((2B∙A)/(π-2θ))∙dϕ/dt,

where dϕ/dt=2πn.

It still isn't equal to the answer that I should be getting.

'The commutator gap can be neglected.' does that mean there will be no flat top and bottom on the graph of flux vs angular position? The graph sort of becomes triangular and even in that case where the theta goes to zero, the required answer is not in sight.
I need insight on it.

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting -Ui=l*d*B*2*pi*n.

Comment: Where did d= duty cycle go?

Comment: d is diameter of a rotor coil

Comment: the duty cycle wasnot mentioned anywhere by the lecturer.

Comment: Ok, not sure how to specify the deadtime of flat top

Comment: the lecturer pointed out that flux and angle have got a linear relationship and he neglected the commutator gap. Is there any simplification required to reach the above derivation?

Comment: Not done that in a long while

Comment: To me it looks like there is one condition less than required to calculate value of θ , are you sure only these conditions are given?

Comment: making the commutator gap negligibly small will get rid of theta I suppose and the solution is just  -Ui=B*l*d*2*pi*n. which I'm not being able to derive.

Comment: huhu i got the answer...